# adding target property to this JS code

Tags: javascript, targets

I want to edit this code:

```
this.link = $('<a>Directions</a>').addClass('mapplic-tooltip-link').attr('href', '#').hide().appendTo(this.el);
```

to open in a new window. I've looked online but I don't know how to edit this. Any help would be much appreaciated.

Comment: Do you understand what that code does? Because the answer to your question is 90% in there.

Comment: Hint: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
this.link = $('<a>Directions</a>')
            .addClass('mapplic-tooltip-link')
            .attr('href', '#')
            .attr('target', '_blank').hide().appendTo(this.el);
```

just add another property attr to your link with the **target** key and **blank** value.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
var el = $('#id');
var link = $('<a>')
            .addClass('mapplic-tooltip-link')
            .text('Directions')
            .attr({'href': '#','target': '_blank'})
            .hide()// this hide content
            .appendTo(el);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id"></div>
```